# PHP inserting data to mySQL two times instead of one

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "test";

$name="admin";
$pass="passerino";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else {
  echo nl2br("Conected \n");
}
$sqlin="INSERT INTO data_test (username, password) VALUES ('valname','valpass')";
$result=$conn->query($sqlin);
if ($conn->query($sqlin) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
 echo "Error: " . $sqlin . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }
 $conn->close();
 include_once "read.php";
 ?>
```

Hello i have this simple .php file to insert data into mySQL database,but instead of once it does it two times with one request.How can i stop this?I am using wamp server x64,chrome,php 5.5.12;
P.S read.php displays the data table

Comment: `$result=$conn->query($sqlin);
if ($conn->query($sqlin) === TRUE) {`   - What did you expect?

Comment: as @Naruto has said.  you executed your query twice `$conn->query($sqlin)`

Comment: stupid me,i did not know that if condition would actually execute  the statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this code

```
    $sqlin="INSERT INTO data_test (username, password) VALUES ('valname','valpass')";
    $result=$conn->query($sqlin);
    if ($conn->query($sqlin) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
     echo "Error: " . $sqlin . "<br>" . $conn->error;
     }
     $conn->close();
     include_once "read.php";
```

to

```
$sqlin="INSERT INTO data_test (username, password) VALUES ('valname','valpass')";
$result=$conn->query($sqlin);
if ($result === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
 echo "Error: " . $sqlin . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }
 $conn->close();
 include_once "read.php";
```

Because if you run this line `$conn->query($sqlin);` twice it will run your query twice and insert record in database two time

Answer (score 2):

Because you are execution your query times

```
$result=$conn->query($sqlin);// first time
if ($conn->query($sqlin) === TRUE) {// second time
```

Just execute it only one time

```
$sqlin="INSERT INTO data_test (username, password) VALUES ('valname','valpass')";
if ($conn->query($sqlin) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
 echo "Error: " . $sqlin . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }
```

Don't insert value directly better use bind statement

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Don't store plain password into database read password hashing

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Answer (score 0):

Do not take result variable directly do as follows :

```
if ($conn->query($sqlin) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
 echo "Error: " . $sqlin . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the variable in your if condition

```
if($sqlin === TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`$conn->query($sqlin) === TRUE` causes an dual entry use `$result === TRUE`  instead.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's a great issue. you have to check view file. That's means, focus on your file where you called class. You called 2 times. If you are not using any success message. It should to ok, but if you use it, so please remove another call. Suppose -

**Example:**

```
$_SESSION ['success'] = "Data save successfully";
```

or

```
$success_msg = "Data save successfully";
```

(from main public function)

**you have to call on view file -**

```
$save_blog_info = new Blog();
$success_msg = $save_blog_info->save_blog_info($_POST);
```

**don't use -**

```
$save_blog_info = new Blog();
$save_blog_info->save_blog_info($_POST);
$success_msg = $save_blog_info->save_blog_info($_POST);
```

thanks